# Docker : run service on specific nodes using --placement-pref

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, docker-machine

Can you help me please ?

I want to update a service and run it tasks on specific **nodes** with **placement-pref**.

Actually I have 3 nodes (hostname):

**Manager** : ip-172-31-16-167

**Worker-1** : ip-172-31-30-215

**Worker-2** : ip-172-31-24-172

And I have deploy service **"myapp_vote"** with **2 tasks** (replicas) which are running on **Manager** and **Worker-1**, I want to run these tasks on **Worker-1** and **Worker-2** so I execute the following commands :

```
docker node update --label-add Vote=true ip-172-31-30-215

docker node update --label-add Vote=true ip-172-31-24-172

docker service update --placement-pref-add 'spread=node.labels.Vote' myapp_vote
```

But nothing happened, the 2 tasks continue to run on Manager and Worker-1...

I tried to add constraint with the following command :

```
docker service update --constraint-add 'node.labels.Vote == true' myapp_vote
```

It worked and the 2 tasks start to run on **Worker-1** and **Worker-2**.

Please is it possible to do the same thing but with **placement-pref** ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with the only placement-pref [because](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#placement-preferences):

> Nodes which are missing the label used to spread still receive task
>   assignments. As a group, these nodes receive tasks in equal proportion
>   to any of the other groups identified by a specific label value. In a
>   sense, a missing label is the same as having the label with a null
>   value attached to it. If the service should **only** run on nodes with the
>   label being used for the spread preference, the preference should be
>   combined with a constraint.